# What is the scope and benefits of big data?

Tags: bigdata

What can you do after learning big data related concepts, Hadoop, ML, NLP etc? Where can you implement these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a software related question - but it's very relevant to current technology and why some software exists. So here is an opinion.

We now live in a world where it is possible to monitor and digitally record information on an epic scale that continues to expand with concepts like [The Internet of Things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_Things).

With this information it becomes possible to look at the evidence behind decisions that previously would have been made by gut instinct or opinions. What impact does road design have on traffic flow? Which medical drugs get best results in the real world and not just in drugs trials? Is there a correlation between office temperature and productivity? and so on for millions of questions in different domains.

Around the world, organisations are using data they never previously had, to get better at whatever they do (Good or bad).

The big data concepts are the tools for managing all this information. Big Data is not just large in volume, it is often unstructured and in different forms.

So to answer your question. You can implement these concepts by working with [organisations](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/PoweredBy) that are using Big Data. Hopefully you can see the potential of Big Data along with the mind bending headache it can create when trying to make sense of it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the good response, helped me a lot! Sorry for replying late.